# Подсчет пробелов от точки до точки

Tags: python

Есть пару предложений: (это просто пример)

"Современный мир. Получать удовольствие. Вызывают раздражение. Опрошено большое количество людей. Многие с этим согласны."

**Задача**
-подсчитать пробелы от первой точки до второй точки.
-подсчитать пробелы от второй точки до третей точки.
-подсчитать пробелы от третей точки до четвертой точки.

Мой кривой код:

```
a = "Современный мир. Получать  удовольствие. Вызывают раздражение. Опрошено большое количество людей. Многие с этим согласны."

b = re.findall('\.', a)    # нахожу все точки
print(b[0:2], a.count(" ")) # тут ошибка
```

Как завтавить его посчитать пробелы не во всем тексте, а именно от первой точки до второй?

Comment: Ну для начала оформите ваш код в блок кода. А вообще вы смотрели, что возвращает `re.findall`? Сейчас он просто разбивает вашу строку на символы, так как '.' - это специальных символ. Чтобы искать именно точки, его нужно экранировать: '\.'. Кроме того, `findall` возвращает список строк, а не индексов. Чтобы получить индексы можно использовать другую функцию: `[i.start() for i in re.finditer('\.', a)]` или просто написать, что нужно самому: `[i for i, e in enumerate(a) if e == '.']`. Чтобы потом найти количество пробелов между точкам, нужно использовать срезы: `a[b[i]:b[i+1]].count(' ')`

Comment: Простите пожалуйста, я абсолютный новичок в питоне и на stackoverflow, это мой первый вопрос на здесь, потихоньку буду разбираться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без использования re-гулярок:

```
a = "Современный мир. Получать удовольствие. Вызывают раздражение. Опрошено большое количество людей. Многие с этим согласны."
start_ind = 0
while start_ind < len(a)-1:
    start_ind = a.find('.',start_ind)
    end_ind = a.find('.',start_ind+1)
    print(a[start_ind:end_ind].count(' '))
    start_ind = end_ind
# 2, 2, 4, 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Уберите из строки всё кроме точек и пробелов. Разбейте строку по точкам. Измерьте длины пробельных кусочков. Напечатайте, те что вам нужны:

```
import re


a = "Современный мир. Получать  удовольствие. Вызывают раздражение. Опрошено большое количество людей. Многие с этим согласны."
b = re.sub('[^ .]', '', a)  # ' .   .  .    .    .'
c = b.split('.')            # [' ', '   ', '  ', '    ', '    ', '']
d = list(map(len, c))       # [1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 0]
print(d[1])
print(d[2])
print(d[3])
```

> ```
> $ python count-spaces.py
> 3
> 2
> 4
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "Современный мир. Получать удовольствие. Вызывают раздражение. Опрошено большое количество людей. Многие с этим согласны."
n = a.split(".")
if a.endswith("."):
    n = a.split(".")[:-1]
ans = [f"От {i} до {i + 1} точки = {n[i].count(' ')} пробел." for i in range(1, len(n))]
print(ans)
```

Пытался сначала с помощью модуля re сделать, но потом передумал. Вот, что получилось